# Nested Filtering Using Ipywidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, widget, ipywidgets

I am trying to create a dynamic filtering with Ipywidgets. The word dynamic here refers to: if an option is chosen in one widget, it will affect the choices of the remaining widgets.

Here is a toy dataset for replication purposes.

```
toy_data = pd.DataFrame({"LETTER": ["A", "B", "A","B","A", "B", "A","B"],
               "PLANT": ["Orange", "Carrots", "Lemon","Potato","Pomelo","Yam","Lime","Radish"],
               "NUMBER": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

Creating widgets:

```
letter_var = widgets.Dropdown(
    description="Letter: ",
    options=toy_data.LETTER.unique(),
    value="A",
)

def letter_filtering(change):
    clear_output(wait = True)
    letter = letter_var.value
    new_toy_data = toy_data[toy_data.LETTER == str(letter)]
    
    plant_var = widgets.Dropdown(description="Plant: ", options=new_toy_data.PLANT.unique(), value="Orange")
    
    return plant_var
```

the purpose of the letter_filtering function is to filter the choices in the wigets for plants. That is if the letter B has been chosen for letter_var, the choices in plant_var will only be limited to the letter B. but upon implementation,

```
widgets.HBox([letter_var,letter_filtering])
```

I am receiving a trait error.

```
TraitError: The 'children' trait of a HBox instance contains an Instance of a TypedTuple which expected a Widget, not the function 'letter_filtering'.
```

I think I'm lost on how to go about this.

Comment: widgets.HBox expects to get a list of widgets. letter_var is a widget, but letter_filtering is a function. You need to define the plant_var widget outside of the letter_filtering function, and when a selection is made in the letter_var widget, you should call the letter_filtering function on selection to set the value of the plant_var widget. As things are now, whilst the letter_filtering function returns a widget (plant_var), the function is never called! If you try to rewrite your code and update here, I'll be happy to help you if you have any problems. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the widget mechanism, but you can achieve this via the "interact" functionality, which I think is also simpler:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, fixed

toy_data = pd.DataFrame({"LETTER": ["A", "B", "A","B","A", "B", "A","B"],
               "PLANT": ["Orange", "Carrots", "Lemon","Potato","Pomelo","Yam","Lime","Radish"],
               "NUMBER": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

def inner_fn(plant, df_in):
    df_ = df_in if plant == 'ALL' else df_in[df_in['PLANT'] == plant]
    return df_

def outer_fn(letter):
    df_ = toy_data if letter == 'ALL' else toy_data[toy_data['LETTER'] == letter]
    plants = ['ALL'] + sorted(df_['PLANT'].unique())
    interact(inner_fn, plant=plants, df_in=fixed(df_))

letters = ['ALL'] + sorted(toy_data['LETTER'].unique())
interact(outer_fn, letter=letters)
```

This will create a "plant" dropdown underneath the "letter" dropdown, like so:

[image: Starting point]

And when a letter is chosen, the list of plants will update, like so:

[image: updated plant list]

The little extra indentation of the second dropdown box is a tip-off that this is a nested mechanism and admittedly makes this technique a bit unsightly.